# Find $U+V$ given $U\alpha^{-5} + V\beta^{-5} = 22$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Find $U+V$ given $U\alpha^{-5} + V\beta^{-5} = 22$, when $\alpha, \beta$ are roots 
>   of $x^2-x-1$ and $U,V$ are **integers**.

For simplicity I only show the U term:
$$U+V = U\alpha^{-5}\alpha^{5}+ ... \\ = U \alpha^{-5}(\alpha^4 \alpha)\\
 = U \alpha^{-5}((\alpha+1)^2 \alpha)+ ...\\
 =U \alpha^{-5}((\alpha +1) \alpha + 2(\alpha+1) + \alpha)+ ... \\
 = U \alpha^{-5}(\alpha +1+\alpha + 2 \alpha + 2 + \alpha)+ ...\\ = U \alpha^{-5 }(5\alpha + 3) + ... \\
 = 5 U \alpha^{-4}+5V\beta^{-4} + 3 \cdot 22 $$

Now How to get rid of $\alpha^{-4}, \beta^{-4}$? Please help me, do give hints only.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes they are integers, U and V are integers, I missed it.

Comment: That is better! + 1.

Comment: This can actually be done in a really straightforward manner if you just work out what $\alpha^{-5}$ and $\beta^{-5}$ are.  They are just numbers of the form $\dfrac{A \pm \sqrt{B}}{C}$.  Then plug that in and the result pops out.

Comment: @Daniel I know $\alpha, \beta$ as $\frac{1\pm \sqrt 5}{2}$

Comment: $x^2-x-1$ is irreducible, its roots $\alpha,\beta$ are Galois conjugate to each other. If "$U \alpha^{-5} + V\beta^{-5} = 22$", a relation with rational coefficients is true, so does the relation "$U\beta^{-5} + V\alpha^{-5} = 22$". This leads to $(U+V)(\alpha^{-5} + \beta^{-5}) = 44$ and you only need to figure out what $\alpha^{-5} + \beta^{-5}$ is. You can arrive the same conclusion by using the explicit form of $\alpha,\beta = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: @achillehui yes I understand, but that seems a time consuming way, this question had to be done in $< 5$ minutes, it is on mcq exam.

Comment: @jeea Since $\alpha\beta = -1$, $\alpha^{-5} + \beta^{-5} = -(\alpha^5 + \beta^5)$. Now the sequence $u_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n$ satisfy a recurrence relation of the form $u_{n+1} = u_{n} + u_{n-1}$. Computing $u_5$ from $u_0 = 2, u_1 = 1$ takes only tens of seconds.

Comment: No issue. You may see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with $\alpha^2 = \alpha + 1$ and $\beta^2 = \beta + 1$ since these satisfy $x^2  = x+1$. Clearly, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are non-zero.

Now, $\alpha^{-1}  = \alpha - 1$. Square both sides : $\alpha^{-2} = \alpha^2 - 2\alpha + 1 = 2 - \alpha$. Squaring again, $\alpha^{-4} = (2-\alpha)^2 =$ $ 4 - 4 \alpha + \alpha^2 = 5 - 3 \alpha$. Another $\alpha$ multiplication gives $\alpha^{-5} = 5\alpha^{-1} - 3 = 5\alpha - 8$. Can you see the Fibonacci sequence here?

The exact same applies for $\beta$.

Therefore, $U\alpha^{-5} + V \beta^{-5} = U(5 \alpha  - 8) + V(5 \beta- 8) = 22$. Hence, $5\alpha U + 5\beta V = 22 + 8(U+V)$.

Hence, $5(1 + \sqrt 5)U + 5(1 - \sqrt 5)V = 44 + 16(U+V)$, rewrite to $5\sqrt{5}(U-V) = 44 + 11(U+V)$. Hence, we get that $U-V = 0$ otherwise the LHS will be irrational and hence $44 = -11(U+V)$ so $U+V = -4$. Of course, we get $U= V = -2$ from here.

Key idea :  if $\alpha$ is the root of a quadratic equation, higher powers of $\alpha$ can be expressed as $c \alpha + d$ for some $c,d$.

Comment: Oh now I understand, thanks actoh!

Comment: Brilliant. By the way, I suspect this should take under five minutes for completion, with practice.